# Redirect after login different for customer group on Prestashop

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, prestashop-1.6

i need to put some change on my website but i have some problem.

I have 2 role group (user and reseller). I need that when reseller login go on "my account page" and when user login redirect to previsure page.

I try to change this line on authentication.top

```
{if is_array($customerGroups)}
{if $customerGroups[0]['id_group'] == 4}
{if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
else
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER}" />
```

I have this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught 
--> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "/home/mysite/public_html/themes/default-bootstrap/authentication.tpl" on line 760 "" unclosed {if} tag 
<-- thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 760
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to put a closed tag

```
{/if}
```

Comment: Hello, yes sorry my distraction error. But this not work. If i try to put there is no different to redirect between user group. Even type user redirect to "my-account" page. 

If i put simple `<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER}" />` functions and redirect to previsour page. But if i use conditional to change redirect link in relationshipt with ID role..not function for nothing.